# Image Proxier - Replace and collate images on StackOverflow

Tags: script

### About

This will replace all links from `["https://i.stack.imgur.com/", "https://i.imgur.com/"]` with links from "https://web.archive.org/web/" (by default, this can be changed relatively easy).

This will also collate links to images found near each other in comments or answers/questions as thumbnails that you can click to view a larger version of the image.

The main purpose of this script is for people who do not have access to imgur images for whatever reason.

This script has some flags that can be set in the source code if you do not like certain features they can be disabled. You can even disable the proxy part itself if you just like the way the pictures are collated.

### Install

[GreasyFork](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/38427-image-proxier/code/Image%20Proxier.user.js)

[GitHub](https://github.com/GrumpyCrouton/Userscripts)

### Screenshots

[image]

You can then click on the image to see a bigger version of it:

[image]

On images *inside* questions, it will similarly collate all of the images together, but only ones near eachother in paragraphs. If multiple images exist in a paragraph, they will all be collated together right above where they originally had been.

[image]

---

I've never posted here before, so if I missed something, or something is in the wrong format please let me know.